# calling a async function inside then

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
func().then(function (result){
   var a = func1(result);
   func2(a).then(function(result1){
    ////
   }
}
```

As you can see `func` returns a promise, and in then part we call another `func1` which also returns a promise. Is it possible to chain the promise returned from `func2` with the promise of then, and somehow get ride of the nested functions in the second then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return value inside a `then()` function is used as a promise value itself. So you can easily return the new promise and keep on chaining here:

```
func()
  .then(function (result){
    var a = func1(result);
    return func2(a);
  })
  .then(function(result1){
    ////
  })
```

See [2.2.7](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-41) and [2.3.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-41) of the Promise A+ Spec.