# insert async function inside then

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I want make a Get Request with `axios` get method and chain a post Request if the `Promise` is successful

Endpoint is a API the `Promise` who should return the `Promise` from the `Get Request` returns the `GET Request Promise`

considering this answer [calling a async function inside then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32384155/12753324) this should be possibly

why does the post request gets not trough ?

```js
axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/')
.then(() => {
    data = {
        email: 'eve.holt@reqres.in',
        password: 'pistol'
    }
    return data
}).then((data) => {
    const postRequest = axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/register', data);
    return postRequest
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
}).catch((response) => {
    console.log(response)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Http Requests & JavaScript</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [docs/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [understanding-async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512388/understanding-async-await-on-nodejs)

If you use async, how about using `await`? I have now translated your code using `await`.

```js
// test.js
const axios = require('axios');

const test = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/');
        const data = {
            email: 'eve.holt@reqres.in',
            password: 'pistol'
        }
        const registerResult = await axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/register', data);
        console.log(registerResult);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

test();
```

- After waiting for the `axios.get()` function to execute **normally**, `axios.post()` will be executed.
- If an **error** is returned from `axios.get()` process, an error is `thrown` and it will be **stopped immediately**. then, the error is logged in the `catch()` function.
- (Of course) Also, even if `axios.get()` function works normally, if a problem occurs in `axios.post()` function, it will `catch()` error.

[P.S] Additionally if you want to get the result by `axios.get()`, you can use it after assigning the result to a variable like `const users = await axios.get()`

Comment: `async/await` looks so clean compared to the `.then().then()` Promise style, or even worse, a good old callback hell. Upvoted, that's the way to go

Comment: I just realized that my code also works, but your solution looks way cleaner !